# Back ground color changing code changes it self

Tags: html

when I try to change **"Body Background"** color from `f23a03`, it is not accepting the change and makes change it self to color no. `f23b03` instead of my original color. could you please help me in this? I made several attempts with the `f23a03` but all failed while yesterday it was accepting. I am working on "Website Builder" to make my website (with hostinger.com)

I have tried color coding with `f23a03` but it automatically makes `f23b03`.

I need `f23a03` color code

I made several attempts with the f23a03 but all failed while yesterday it accepted.

Answer (score 0):

use rgba for #f23a03

```
rgba(242,58,3,1.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This in your style file:-

```css
body {
 background-color: #f23a03 !important; // Or using rgba(242, 58, 3, 1)
}
```

```html
<body>
The content of the body element is displayed in your browser.
</body>
```